# Destacar um horário com PHP que esteja guardado no banco

Tags: php

Estou criando uma pequena tabela que possui 7 colunas, a primeira linha de cada coluna representa um dia e as restantes são horários daquele dia.

Desejo que os horários que estejam guardados no banco sejam destacados nessa tabela. Tentei de algumas maneiras, não tive sucesso e gostaria de uma ajuda.

Aqui está o código, e já peço desculpas por qualquer erro básico, ainda não sou muito familiarizado com PHP.

```
<table border="1">      
<?php
    $query = array();
    echo '<tr>';
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 7; $i++) {
        $data = date('d-m-Y',strtotime('+' . $i . ' days'));
        $query[$i] = mysql_query ("SELECT hora_consulta FROM consulta WHERE data_consulta =  '$data'");
        echo '<td>' . $data . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';

    $horario = '08:00';

    while (strtotime($horario) < strtotime('20:00')) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $horario . '</td>' .
             '<td>' . $horario . '</td>' .
             '<td>' . $horario . '</td>' .
             '<td>' . $horario . '</td>' .
             '<td>' . $horario . '</td>' .
             '<td>' . $horario . '</td>' .
             '<td>' . $horario . '</td>' ;

        $horario = strtotime("$horario + 30 minutes");
        $horario = date("H:i",$horario);
        echo '</tr>';
    }

?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que é isso que você deseja:

```
/*
* Inseri datas e horas no banco (apaguei algumas para simulação)

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $data = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("today + $i days 08:00:00"));
    for ($a = 0; $a <= 8; $a++) {
    $data = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("$data + 1 hours"));
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO dias_horas (data_hora) VALUES ('$data')") or die(mysql_error());
}
}*/

    echo "<table border=\"1\">";

$data_inicial = $data_loop = date("Y-m-d"); //Data de hoje 
$data_final = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("$data_inicial + 10 days"));

$data_aux = array();//Array que armazenará as datas e horas do banco de dados

$busca = mysql_query("SELECT data_hora FROM dias_horas ORDER BY data_hora");
while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($busca)) {
    $data_aux[] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($data["data_hora"]));
}


echo "<tr>";
while ($data_loop <= $data_final) { //O loop para o intervalo de dias
    echo "<th>" . date("d/m/Y", strtotime($data_loop)) . "</th>";
    $data_loop = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($data_loop . " + 1 days"));
}
echo "</tr>";


for ($i = 0; $i < 24; $i++) { //Loop para as horas do dia
    $data_loop = $data_inicial;
    echo "<tr>"; //Cada hora é em uma linha
    while ($data_loop <= $data_final) {
        echo "<td";
        /*Se houver aquela data e hora que o loop está percorrendo
        dentro do array, imprime o estilo negrito
        */
        echo in_array(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($data_loop . " $i:00:00")), $data_aux) ? " style='font-weight:bold'" : "";
        echo ">$i:00</td>";
    $data_loop = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($data_loop . " + 1 days"));
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
?>`
```

Comment: Exatamente o que eu precisava, muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

Olá. pelo que entendi. Você quer destacar seu horário com uma cor diferente? 
Se sim. Você pode adicionar uma `tag html`, exemplo: `<red>` ou um `style color` em `css`

```
echo "<td>".$horario."</td>
      <td><red>".$horario."</red></td>
      <td style='color:#FFFFFF'>".$horario."</td>
      <td><s>".$horario."</s></td>
      <td><b>".$horario."</b></td>
      <td><red>".$horario."</red></td>
      <td><blue>".$horario."</blue></td>" ;
```

Comment: Isso, mas gostaria de fazer conforme alguns dados no banco, mas obrigado pela resposta!